# Multer cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, multipartform-data, multer

I'm trying to upload pdf file but I got an error called cannot read property 'filename' of undefined. Below code is working on postman and also working when I change form element like this:

form(action=`/api/v1/student/ad/${ad.id}` method="POST" 'enctype="multipart/form-data")

But not working with axios.

Pug File:

```
form.applyAdForm
    input(type='file' accept='.pdf' id='cv' name='cv')
    label(for='cv') Upload CV
    button.btn Apply
```

JS File connected to the Pug File:

```
const applyAdForm = document.querySelector('.applyAdForm');
 if (applyAdForm) {
  applyAdForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = document.getElementById('cv').files[0];
    formData.append('cv', file);
    applyAdAxios(formData);
  });
}
```

Axios File:

```
 export const applyAdAxios = async formData => {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/v1/student/ad/id',
          data: {
            formData
          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
```

Route File:

```
 const router = express.Router();
    router.post(
      '/ad/:id',
      adController.uploadStudentCV,
      adController.applyAd
    );
```

adController File:

```
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/pdf/cvs');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    cb(null, `user-${req.user.id}-${Date.now()}.${ext}`);
  }
});
const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('application/pdf')) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new AppError('Lütfen pdf dosyası yükleyiniz', 400), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
  fileFilter: multerFilter
});
exports.uploadStudentCV = upload.single('cv');

exports.applyAd = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  await AdApply.create({
    student: req.user.id,
    ad: req.params.id,
    cv: req.file.filename
  });
  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success'
  });
});
```

**Solution:**
I have no idea why but the problem is curly brackets around formData variable. I changed axios part like this:

```
export const applyAdAxios = async formData => {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/v1/student/ad/id',
          data: formData
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
```

And it is now working.

Comment: The error is from `exports.applyAd`, but, you have another function called `applyAd` so it's hard to tell which is which. Could you edit your question to specify which is being used and where?

Comment: I edited the names. First 3 files are in client-side and last 2 files are in server-side.